# How to add or modify account_signTransaction function

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

In this `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/external/backend.go` of Ethereum project i see the "account_signTransaction" function and i want to edit or update the logic for this function, where must i find it. i searched and not found anywhere.

Thanks so much.